# how to match exact word in csv file?

Tags: python

I am a beginner coder here and I am trying to do a simple registration/login system using an external csv file.

my issue--> let's say I have an existing user "john" when my program promts for a name during registration and I enter the letter j or jo or joh

output --> user existed

how can I solve this issue?

```
import csv

name = input("register your name: ")
name=name.replace(" ", "")
with open("datafile.csv","r") as file:
    content=file.read()
    loop=True
    while loop!=False:
        if name in content :
            name = input("name taken pls try again: ")
            name=name.replace(" ", "")
        else:
            loop=False
        
password=input("new password: ")
with open("datafile.csv","a+",newline="") as file:
    f=csv.writer(file)
    f.writerow([name,password])

def main():
    with open("datafile.csv","r") as file:
        file_reader = csv.reader(file)
        user_find(file_reader)
        file.close()

def user_find(file):
    user = input("Enter your username: ")
    for row in file:
        if row[0] == user:
            print("username found", user)
            user_found = [row[0],row[1]]
            pass_check(user_found)
            break
        else:
            print("not found")

def pass_check(user_found):
    user = input("enter your password: ")
    if user_found[1] == user:
        print("password match")
    else:
        print("password not match")
        

main()
```

Comment: Your code isn't coherent with your problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name in content` checks whether `name` is *anywhere* in the string `content`. `name` may be any string whatsoever, so `'jo' in 'john,his_password'` will happily find that `'jo'` is indeed a substring of the `content` and evaluate to `True`.

You should actually parse the CSV:

```
existing_names = set() # in case the file is empty
with open("datafile.csv") as file:
    existing_names = {
        existing_name
        for (existing_name, _) in csv.reader(file)
    }

while True:
    if name in existing_names:
        name = input("name taken pls try again: ")
        name = name.replace(" ", "")
    else:
        break
```

Comment: with the code u provided, my program now allows multiple john to be registered, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: @qwertyhey65, whoops, indeed, that was a bug. The new code won't allow duplicate names.